# How do I remove unwanted json3 module from my node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, polyfills

I just upgraded my react app to include the newest react router v5.2 in order to get the useHistory hook. Things worked fine until I restarted for the first time next morning. Now when I use f5 to start a debugging session I get an exception in a node-modules file named json3. (BTW, the app runs okay in the browser after yarn start.) The exception is "SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 1". The code is line 186 in json3.js:

```
186   parseSupported = !parse('"\t"');
```

I read the json3 README.md and it says: "JSON 3 is **deprecated** and **no longer maintained**. Please don't use it in new projects, and migrate existing projects to use the native `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` instead. **JSON 3** was a JSON polyfill for older JavaScript platforms." I don't know how this was installed and I don't think I need it. It's not listed in my package.json. It's at the top level in node_modules. How do I remove this?

Just in case it's needed, my package.json is this:

```
{
  "name": "blue-duck-pwa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "1.1.4",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "2.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "cheerio": "0.19.x",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "rc-dropdown": "^2.1.0",
    "rc-menu": "^6.2.5",
    "react": "16.13.0",
    "react-auto-suggest": "^0.0.12",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "2.6.4",
    "react-dom": "16.13.0",
    "react-notification-system": "0.2.16",
    "react-portal": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scrollchor": "^4.2.1",
    "react-sizes": "1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I _think_ you can first delete it from your package.json, then delete your node_modules, followed by a fresh `npm install`

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules folder and then run npm install.

Comment: I just tried running yarn install without the node_module folder, and json3 was added again in the new node_modules

Comment: @jagraj singh By a process of elimination and retrying a yarn install with different files deleted from package.json, I see that it is react-scripts that add json3 to node_modules. my original react-scripts v1.1.0 did it and so did the latest react-scripts v3.4.3. So what can I do? I need react-scripts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the conflicts I caused by upgrading my node_modules without regard to breaking changes (dumb I know), I was only able to fix this problem by starting over. I made another create-react-app, copied my package.json (with the corrected version numbers), ran yarn install, then copied over all my program data: src, .vscode, .eslintrc, etc, etc. With a few easy fixes, this worked. No exceptions deep in the node_modules.